Azure Deployment - Server Error (500). Environmental Variables Error?
my azure environmental variables
OPENAI_API_KEY = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
This doesn't seem to be working for azure deployment? What other steps do I need to make to ensure my azure deployed website can access my openai api key?
I have created a vector database driven website using django. I am able to run the webapp and perform searches using the api key on local host. I am able to do this while connected to the azure database.
However, when I access my website through the public domain, I can't seem to perform searches. I've added the api key to the azure environmental variables already. It says Server Error 500 when I try to perform searches.
Is there anything else I need to do? What could be causing server error 500?

Unfortunately, this question doesn't provide enough details for us to be able to help you. Are you sure it's the OpenAI API Key that's triggering the 500 Error? What error message are you getting? Can you access other environment variables from code? Could you show some relevant code?
